# How to handle multiple usercontrols in windows 8?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-8

In my mainpage i added around 15 user controls and 10 more button images.Whenever click on particular button image displaying corresponding usercontrol.usercontrol having close button to close that control.my question is if user not closing particular usercontrol  and click on another button image it's displaying another usercontrol.How to close previuos usercontrol when click on another button image. general idea we can disabling usercontrols by it's visibilty property when click on other button.But in my case so many usercontrols and buttons are there.it's hectic to write code like that for close previous usercontrols .Any other ideas to close that ?

Comment: you can use messenger class for sending message to usercontrol you want close..

Comment: can you provide me any samples links..

Comment: you are usin mvvm light right ?

Comment: no .I haven't using MVVM right now.

Comment: so what you can do is you can make the button eventhandlers static and then use them..on other usercontrols click event too..you have to use some workaround because u are not using mvvm..

Comment: can you follow up me with a sample..